# Insert data in a SQL Server table when table name, column names and values are given as variables in Insert statement?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, variables, dynamic-sql

I'm trying to create a generic script to copy data from one database to another and I've written this script.

```
USE TargetDatabase;

DECLARE @SourceDatabase NVARCHAR(100);
DECLARE @TargetDatabase NVARCHAR(100);

DECLARE @SourceTable NVARCHAR(100);
DECLARE @TargetTable NVARCHAR(100);

DECLARE @var NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @SourceDatabase = 'SourceDB'
SET @TargetDatabase = 'TargetDB'

SET @SourceTable = 'SourceTable'
SET @TargetTable = 'TargetTable'

set @var = (SELECT STRING_AGG (QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME), ',') from 
@TargetDatabase.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME = @TargetTable);
```

As you can see below, in the **INSERT** statement I'm giving Table Name, Column Name and Values as a variable. This is where I'm having problems, so basically I don't know how to evaluate these variables **@var, @SourceTable, @TargetTable**.

```
INSERT INTO @TargetTable (SELECT @Var)
SELECT * FROM @SourceTable
```

I'm stuck here and I don't know how to solve this issue. Can any one explain how I can solve this problem?

Comment: Google dynamic SQL. But really this isn't the way to do things in SQL - its aimed at specific table actions, not generic actions.

Comment: Don't. There are far better ways of solving this problem, including but not limited to using the data import/export wizards of Management Studio, (client!) generated statements, using `SqlBulkCopy` from client code or using any number of third-party ETL tools. Of all languages to do ETL in T-SQL is ironically one of the least convenient because of its lack of dynamic typing and poor string handling; the only thing it has going for it is that it's close to the database.

Comment: I know its aimed at a specific table but I'll be putting it in an another script once i solve this issue. @DaleK

Answer (score 0):

There are many other ways to run a dynamic query but here is one way you can run your query as per your requirements.

```
declare @table nvarchar(50)
declare @query nvarchar(500)

set @table = 'Test'

set @query='insert into [' +@table+ '] Select * from [' +@table+ ']';

Exec sp_executesql @query;
```